# URL appendPathComponent(_:) deprecated?

Tags: swift, url, deprecated

The official doc says it's deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780397-appendpathcomponent

[image]

What's the replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement is [`append(path:directoryHint:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3988445-append).

If you use Xcode's code completion you can see this clearly. Type something like:

```
someUrl.append
```

and Xcode shows a list of possible matches. It will show the deprecated method with a mention of the replacement.

[image]

Another option is to right-click on the use of `appendPathComponent` in your code and select "Jump to Definition". That will take you to an interface file for Foundation.URL where you will see something like:

```
/// Appends a path component to the URL.
///
/// - note: This function performs a file system operation to determine if the path component is a directory. If so, it will append a trailing `/`. If you know in advance that the path component is a directory or not, then use `func appendingPathComponent(_:isDirectory:)`.
/// - parameter pathComponent: The path component to add.
@available(macOS, introduced: 10.9, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use append(path:directoryHint:) instead")
@available(iOS, introduced: 7.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use append(path:directoryHint:) instead")
@available(tvOS, introduced: 9.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use append(path:directoryHint:) instead")
@available(watchOS, introduced: 2.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Use append(path:directoryHint:) instead")
public mutating func appendPathComponent(_ pathComponent: String)
```

The `@available` lines show the replacement. This is how Xcode can show the replacement. Not sure why the online documentation and Xcode's Developer Documentation window don't show the replacement.

Comment: bad apple documentation. it's weird to me that xcode has more info than their online docs.

Comment: @Hammerhead Just updated the answer with more details that explains how Xcode can show what it does.

Comment: If you marry the web site, Xcode and the wayback machine, you can get a less-incomplete picture about 90% of the time. Personally, I would prefer if they did a clean drop on release.